# jquery замена класса

Tags: jquery

Всем привет. Задача такая - нужно при клике по ссылке сестринскому элементу span присваивать класс badge-danger, в то же время если у сестринских элементов других ссылок из списка есть badge-danger - присвоить badge-info. Написал 2 функции, но они работают только порознь, если вместе - то при клике только присваивается badge-danger, а где он уже есть - не сбрасывается.

```
$("#brain_list li a").click(
    function () {
        if ($('#brain_list li span').hasClass("badge-danger")) {
            $('#brain_list li span').removeClass("badge-danger")
            $('#brain_list li span').addClass("badge-info")
        }
    },

    function () {
        $(this).siblings('span').addClass("badge-danger")
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

решил самостоятельно

```
$("#brain_list li a").click(
    function () {
        $("#brain_list li a").siblings('span').not(this).removeClass("badge-danger").addClass("badge-info");
        $(this).siblings('span').removeClass("badge-info").addClass("badge-danger");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#brain_list li a").click(
function () {

    $(this).siblings('span').addClass("badge-danger");

    $("#brain_list li a").each(function () {
        var t = $(this);
        if (t.hasClass("badge-danger")) {
            t.removeClass("badge-danger")
             .addClass("badge-info");
        }
    });

});
```

если правильно понял, то так должен работать

Comment: не работает. Вернее, работает также как и у меня - присваивает класс badge-danger там, где его нет, и не присваивает badge-info, так где есть badge-danger. Получается, при клике каждый элемент меняет класс только на badge-danger, но ни одни на badge-info.

Comment: сделал правку, пробуй

Comment: нет, результат тот же. я уже сам разобрался, но все равно спасибо

Comment: пожалуйста, можете написать свой ответ, может кому-то будет полезно